# Cast javascript variable to string for use in sql select

Tags: javascript, sql

I have a selectable dropdown in Javascript which works -

```
<p>Show State: </p>
    <select id="State">
        <option value="'%'">All</option>
        <option value="228">Move</option>
        <option value="212">Clean</option>
        <option value="196">Cleaning</option>
        <option value="180">Ready</option>
        <option value="164">Occupied</option>
    </select>
    <script>
    var showstate = document.getElementById("State").value;
    </script>
```

I need to somehow cast showstate to a string variable in php so I can pass it as a variable into a sql:query but am struggling with the correct commands / syntax.

Something like

```
<%
    String chosen = the value that is in the Javascript variable showstate
%>
```

Then

```
<sql:query var="queryresults" dataSource="jdbc/database">
    select

and asset.name like <%=chosen%>
```

Any thoughts appreciated, I know you can do this with forms, hidden fields and buttons, but the dropdown is mostly dynamic and doesn't require the button to refresh / update.

I could use a form, but I need someway to list the 6 specific options in that form selector, i don't know if this is possible

```
        State Name: <input type="text" id="txt_1" name="statename" value="<%=statename%>" >
        <button type="submit">Show</button>
        

<%
    //System.out.println("the value or statename is   "  + statename);
    String chosen = "'%'";
    
    if (statename =="" || statename ==null || statename.equals("all"))
    {
        chosen = "'%'";
    }
    else
    {
        chosen = "'%"+statename+"%'";
    }
    %>
```

Comment: `showstate` is already a string variable. But you will need to add quotes around it for use in an SQL query.

Comment: I think you are struggling with how to get a value from javascript to PHP ... you'll need to "send" it to the back end, not just have some PHP code in the middle of your javascript code

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use showstate directly in the sql query, can I?

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda, was trying to keep it simple (using very old JS and mySQL)

Comment: I have added a form submit option to the original post, but this would need the 6 options listed, rather than an empty field.

Comment: It would be interesting to see how you intend to use this within a SQL query ~ will whatever values passed to PHP be used directly in the SQL i wonder?

Comment: Hello Professor Abronsus, yes passed directly into SQL as a variable (works fine if I use a set subnit with a form field, but I want a dropdown selector). The first option is a wildcard '&' and works fine with sql:query. I suspect the php is probably fairly simple, but way beyond my skills.

Comment: I don't see any PHP here, it looks like some cold fusion

Comment: Once the user has selected a value, to send it to the backend, where the query runs, you have to make a http request to the server and submit the value. You can do that the traditional way using a form, or you can use javascript to make an asynchronous background request using ajax (so it doesn't refresh the whole page). I could be wrong but I think that's the bit you seem to be missing here. And yeah this doesn't seem to be php

Comment: If I use a form and a set submit then the php is easy, I just define a string variable and then populate it with the string value entered into the form and then use the string variable in the sql:query. But I don't want a form with a field, I want a dropdown selector.

Comment: ADyson, can I somehow drop the var showstate (once selected) into a form field, without havein to submit, as I then know how to use that form field in php? Note that I have a page refresh happening automatically every 5 seconds anyway

Comment: @Ralph you need to **STOP** and **LISTEN.** All your premises are **WRONG.** There is no PHP in this code.  sql:query is not PHP. Nobody knows what is it. You should learn first what technology you are using

Comment: Apologies, I should have said embedded JS, not php (as depicted by the <% and %> in the code)

Comment: sql:query is JSTL

Comment: The answer appears to be to use a hidden field, defined just before the dropdown selector, with its id set to the same name as the variable name set by the dropdown.

Comment: `can I somehow drop the var showstate (once selected) into a form field`...yes it would be easy, using javascript, but why would you need to? The `<select` element it came from is already a form field. Just give it a `name` attribute and its value will be submitted when you submit your form, and will be sent to the server for your server-side code to receive and process as normal

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be to use a hidden field, defined just before the dropdown selector, with the hidden field's id set to the same name as the variable name set by the dropdown.